# Firebase Cloud Firestore - Initializing a Collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an chat app in Swift and when the user creates a chatroom for the first time, it obviously doesn't exist yet in Firebase. Only until the first message gets created does everything build out.

When my app first loads, in the viewDidLoad(), I'm setting a reference to the chat at this path (keep in mind it doesn't exist):

```
  reference = db.collection("chatrooms").document("\(chatRoomId)").collection("thread").document("\(threadId)").collection("messages")
```

So when I add my snapshot listener just below this, and the user creates his first message on the thread, the listener doesn't fire for everyone (I assume, anyway, because it doesn't fire for me)

I do like that once you add your first message, it creates the whole document structure above, but this means my first users who might be watching the thread (however unlikely this is) won't get the message.

Is this an uncommon edge case I'm trying to guard against, or do I need to do something like this (pseudo-code)?

```
 IF (this collection doesn't exist yet) THEN
       CREATE GROUP/THREAD/EMPTY MESSAGE COLLECTION
        reference = db.collection("chatrooms").document("\(chatRoomId)").collection("thread").document("\(threadId)").collection("messages")
    ELSE
        reference = db.collection("chatrooms").document("\(chatRoomId)").collection("thread").document("\(threadId)").collection("messages")
 END
```

I was wondering if there is some sort of initializer I can call to make the structure for me, but still set it up so my first message to the collection fires the snapshot listener.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is unnecessary.  There is no formal method required to create a collection.  A collection simply springs into existence when you first write a document into it.  You can listen on an empty collection with no problems, and listeners should be invoked even if the collection wasn't visible in the dashboard at the time it was added.

Comment: Looks like you're right - I just tried and it worked. I must have messed something up before, or didn't place the right breakpoint, who knows. Either way, we're good now, thanks for taking the time to help me. I'll leave this answer up in case it is of any help to another newb like me.